# Azure DevOps connected with Azure AD, but user lists not showing only Authorized Users

Tags: azure-devops

We have our hosted Azure DevOps instance connected to our Azure AD, and within Azure DevOps we have 175 users setup as Stakeholders or Basic users.

I would expect that within DevOps that the list of users to be able to assign Tasks to, or when @ mentioning someone it would be limited to the 175 authorized users, but in both cases, those lists search our entire Active Directory. **Are we missing a setting somewhere that would limit users to those authorized for DevOps**, or do we just have to live with being able to @ mention people who don't have access to DevOps, or attempts to assign tickets to those that don't have access?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the permission to search in Azure AD. You're probably a **Member** in the Azure AD instance that backs Azure DevOps.

If you have the appropriate permission in the Azure AD instance that backs Azure DevOps, you'll be able to search AAD users. If you don't want to see the AAD users, you can change to **Guest** user type in AAD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-user-and-permissions-management?view=azure-devops#q-why-cant-i-find-members-from-my-connected-azure-ad-even-though-im-the-azure-ad-global-admin